# How to give all inputs of a multiple inputs command at one time

Tags: inputs

There are commands which take multiple inputs. My question is about the possibility of defining a new command which take all the inputs of another command at one time (separated by commas).

As an explicit example, after activating calendar (by `M-x calendar`), if one executes the command `M-x calendar-goto-date`, then it asks the `year` (put 2017), then the `Month name` (put July), then the `day` (put 7). It would be nice to give these inputs at one time like `2017,July,7`. This is just an example, the question also arises in other situations.

Comment: For the case of `calendar-goto-date`, you could redefine the function `calendar-read-date`, which is the function that actually asks for the values. In general, I think there is no solution that would work for every command; you'd have to do it separately for each command.